# Where does the double-v come from in "savvy" ? are there other cases in English?

Tags: etymology

Etymology webpages explain the origins, but I found none commenting the presence of the double-v in english.
( it seems pretty unique in English ? appart for the parent words like savvier, etc.
Could it be related to a former version with 'w' - sometimes called double-v - , which would bring it closer to "sage" in French, thanks to the frequent w↔g substitution between the 2 languages ? ).

Comment: Also, consonant-doubling affects the previous vowel. 'Savy' would be expected to rhyme with 'navy, gravy' etc.

Comment: [English question form: Where **does** the double v come from in savvy?] Faut apprendre à poser une question. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not unique. Doubling a consonant to change the sound of the preceding vowel to a short vowel is very common in English.

It's a common orthographic convention used for pronunciation purposes*. For example: compare later v̲s̲ latter, navy v̲s̲ navvy, hoping v̲s̲ hopping, loping v̲s̲ lopping, write v̲s̲ written. The only unusual thing with savvy is that it happens to be two Vs. There are only a few words which use a double V like this: navvy, savvy, and chavvy, lavvy, and all of these are colloquial/slang.

The use of double V in these examples has nothing to do with the English letter W (double-u). The letter W is NEVER (and has never been) pronounced like a V in English unless it's a foreign word/name (typically German), such a Wagner, wunderkind, etc, and even then, many English speakers will use an English W sound, and not a V sound (like the German W sound).  The history behind the English letter W is that it was used to replace the Old English/Anglo Saxon/runic letter Ƿ (wynn), probably because people considered the runic letter to be too close to the Latin P. This happened some time in the early Modern English era, particularly with the advent of printing.

The correlation between French G and English W sounds mainly exists because of borrowings from Norman French (Northern Old French after 1066CE, into Middle English), not other varieties of Old French which existed at that time: Sometimes English has both forms because of separate borrowings at different times from Norman French, and Old French. For example: *warden*, from Norman French *wardein*, Old French *guardenc*. English also later borrowed guardian from Old French. Some of these correlations also have much older roots, for example *ward* came from Old English *weard*, from a Germanic word: also the source of the Norman French words, but guard was borrowed later from Old French *garder*.

Note also that the word *savvy* is a much later addition to Modern English (not Old/Middle English), long after the Norman French G-W confusion issue, and was first attested in 1686 [according to the OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/savvy_v?tab=meaning_and_use#24339754) and the original spelling was *savee* (1686), later *savey* (1828), and the spelling *savvy* is first attested in 1892.

The OED has the following entry for the etymology of savvy, originally used as a verb, and later as an adjective.

> Probably originally via early West African pidgin < either Portuguese
> saber to know, with -v- reflecting a regional (northern and central)
> pronunciation with lenition of /b/ to a fricative between vowels, or
> Spanish saber to know (see sabe v.), with -v- representing the same
> sound in Spanish, subsequently reinforced by association with French
> savoir to know (see savant n.). Compare sabe v.

Source: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “savvy, v.”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1174572391

***Note**: although this is a general spelling rule, unfortunately there are some exceptions. For example: *to put* > *putting* (not *puting*) v̲s̲ *to putt* > *putting*. Both are spelt the same but have two different pronunciations and meanings.

Comment: Thanks. So if I summarize correctly, in proper english one doesn't find double-v, this form only appears on rare slang terms.
Now if the motivation is pronunciation of the previous vowel, I guess it was to get it close to the one of the source language version it was borrowed from ? (if yes, is it the same for the other *vvy you mentioned ) ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Generally, yes.  I wouldn't say these are not "proper English".  They are real English words, but they are not formal English. But yes, these follow a spelling convention that is used now, but was not always used.  The spelling of English has not been the same for ever, although it is conservative. In the past it was much more fluid.

Comment: In theory it could be productive. We just don't have that many candidates with a v near the end.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - yeah. As far as I know, there are really no native English words that end in a solitary V.  Those that do are either foreign loan words like shiv/shivved (to knife/knifed) from Romany (as is chav), or abbreviations like maglev, improv, gov.